# Docker container specific disk quota

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Every Docker container will be configured with 10 GB disk space by default, which is the default configuration of devicemapper and it works for all containers. how can I limit inodes or disk quota to the individual container?

For example :

> container #1 with disk 10GB and 10000 Inode value
>
> container #2 with disk 20GB and 100000 Inode value

Note : I understand that we can change Default value 10GB by using  `docker -d--storage-opt` but this applied to each and every containter.

Question : how can I limit inodes or disk quota to the individual container?

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.12 this is supported for dm, btrfs and zfs. The syntax is:

```
$ docker create -it --storage-opt size=120G fedora /bin/bash
```

Note that the size must (obviously) be above whatever you have set in your daemon opts.

[Relevant docs link.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/set-storage-driver-options-per-container)

Answer (score 0):

As commented in [issue #16670](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16670#issuecomment-147930259) (Allow ability to limit disk space available to a container)

> Some of the existing volume plugins have the ability to create fixed size volumes out-of-band, which can then be mounted on container run.
>   Alternately you could consider writing your own volume plugin which allows you to embed the filesize into the volume name.

The older [issue 3804](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3804#issuecomment-205093171) adds:

> You should store your data in a volume.
>
> AFAIK, the only Docker storage backend which limits container disk by default is devicemapper. You can configure the daemon to adjust that size, so it's not "stuck" in any real sense.
>
> quotas are now supported in devicemapper, zfs, and btrfs.
>   Probably won't ever be supported in aufs or overlay.
>
> Basically, can set `--storage-opt size=1G` at either the daemon level or at runtime.

So there is no per-container quota yet. There can be for volumes, provided the volume plugin supports it.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that always helped me is running

```
systemctl --user stop docker
systemctl --user start docker
```

Of course of you have sudo rights you don't need the `--user`